# How do I get the `run` command working on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, raku

I wanted to try testing Raku code on Windows. I managed to get Windows 11 set up on VirtualBox and the Raku binary installed and I can execute scripts.

However, I cannot seem to get the simplest `run` command to do anything without returning an error:

`run('ls');`

results in:

```
The spawned command 'ls' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1, signal: 0)
  in block <unit> at .\test.txt line 5
```

I also tried with `dir` command, but had the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `ls` program on Windows by default, and `dir` is not an executable that can be run, but rather a Windows command shell built-in. You could try using `shell` instead of `run`, or instead try something like:

`run 'cmd.exe', '/c', 'dir'`

Comment: Follow up: is it possible to execute a powershell command with `run`?

Comment: Ok, looks like I would do `powershell -command "rakubrew list"` or similar